# How to set clicking on opened class in Editor area that navigate the package that contain this class in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

when new sdk of android 4.2.2 or 4.3 comes at that time I have this features in my eclipse
when I click on opened java classes in editor area it automatically navigate to the project of which have this class and open the package in which this class resist

For example there are two projects opened in eclipse Project1 and Project2.
Project1 has package com.test and contain one file Test.java and Project2 has package com.demo and contain one file Demo.java

now both the file Test.java and Demo.java is opened in Editor area,
When I click Test.java in the Package Explorer eclipse navigate to Project1 and If I click Demo.java in the Package Explorer eclipse navigate to Project2

Recently this feature is not enable in Eclipse, how can I enable this ?
I have Eclipse Indigo V3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `Link with Editor` button on the Package (or Project) Explorer view toolbar (top right of the view):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This feature is provided in the package explorer :

[image]

Clicking it will route you to the java class in your package within your project.

Clicking the button left to it will again collapse the whole project for you.